# UL suffix vs uint32_t cast

Tags: c, c99

I have to define constants like this :

```
#define MY_CONSTANT   0xBEEF
```

I want to be sure that my constant will be considered 32 bits.

I have can use a (uint32_t) cast like this :

```
#define MY_CONSTANT   (uint32_t)0xBEEF
```

Or a UL suffix like this :

```
#define MY_CONSTANT   0xBEEFUL
```

Are these two versions fully equivalent?

I would say no, as UL is the equivalent of `unsigned long` and `unsigned long` length may depend on CPU.

The C99 standard ensures that an `uint32_t` integer is 32 bits, but I don't think it ensures that a `UL` suffix does the same.

Comment: @EOF `UINT32_C()` will insure the type is _at least_ 32 bit as in type `uint_least32_t`

Comment: If you have a compiler with a 16-bit `int`, then your constant will be sign extended when not marked as unsigned (or an implementation-defined conversion will take place). You should use a `U` suffix.

Comment: In a few years (???) `UL` will still work, but `(uint32_t)` may not work because it's a optional type that need not exist on platforms where it does not make sense (see [7.20.1.1p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1.1)).

Comment: @chux: right. Could you point to a situation where this would be a problem?

Comment: @EOL With `UINT32_C(0xBEEF)`, `sizeof(MY_CONSTANT) == sizeof(uint32_t)` could fail.  Using `UINT32_C()` does not meet OP's goal of  "my constant will be considered 32 bits.".  Otherwise OP might as well use `0xBEEFUL`.

Comment: @chux: The only way `sizeof(UINT32_C(0xBEEF)) != sizeof(uint32_t)` is if `uint32_t` doesn't exist. In that case, I presume the compilation will fail with a diagnostic, which would happen *anyway* if you cast to `(uint32_t)`.

Comment: @EOL Agree that the example code given is broke.  So how about `printf("%" PRIu32, UINT32_C(0xBEEF))`? or `if (UINT32_C(0xBEEF) << 16)`?  Can you think of some?

Comment: @chux: The `printf("%" PRIu32, UINT32_C(0xBEEF))` would not compile due to `PRIu32` not being available. But I'll grant you the shift (obviously only a problem for something like `UINT32_C(0xBEEF0000) << 16`), though I find that code somewhat unlikely to occur naturally.

Comment: @EOF `UINT32_C()` being wider than `uint32_t` need only be expected on platforms that do not support `uint32_t`.  In that case, the code would fail with `(uint32_t)0xBEEF`.  So the remaining reason for using `(uint32_t)0xBEEF` vs. `UINT32_C(0xBEEF)` is to insure code fails compilation.  Thanks for the challenging comments.

Comment: @chux: If your codebase is using `UINT32_C()`, it's *probably* also using `uint32_t`, unless it *deliberately* uses `uint_least32_t` to run on some ancient 36-bit word dinosaur. Which would be *weird*, I mean the fixed-width integer types are pretty new, which would indicate somebody wrote new C99-code for some dusty big iron. Oh, well.

Answer (score 6):

You're right, they're not equivalent for the reason you mention. There's no guarantee that `uint32_t` is an alias for `unsigned long`. Include the cast in the `#define`s if necessary.

You should use the parentheses, see comment by @Keith Thompson for a very good reason why; otherwise `sizeof` won't work.

Comment: In fact, in 64-bit implementations, `unsigned long` is often 64-bit.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models

Comment: Should the define be `((uint32_t)0xBEEF)` vs `(uint32_t)0xBEEF`?  `()` to preserve evaluation order?

Comment: You need parentheses. Without them, `sizeof MY_CONSTANT` expands to `sizeof (uint32_t)0xBEEF`, which is a syntax error; the parenthesized type name is taken as the operand of the `sizeof`.

Comment: @KeithThompson D'oh. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The suffix corresponding to `uint32_t` is not necessarily `UL` (it's usually `U` on 32 bit and 64 bit architectures).

Apart from that, a cast might possibly truncate an integer constant that's wider, but its corresponding suffix wouldn't ever cast down, only up.

(See [this table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47206691/1084774) for how suffixes work with integer constants in different bases.)

Comment: Note; A `U` may be usually 32-bit, yet many embedded processors use 16-bit `unsigned` in 2017 (100s millions).

Comment: @chux Thanks. Edited the answer to make it more inclusive :).