# Is there a portable literal suffix for int64_t and similar types?

Tags: c++, c++17, portability

I was trying to understand std::variant:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <variant>

std::variant<int64_t, double> v;
```

I wanted to assign an int64_t variant: `v = 5L;`
That compiles on x86_64 because int64_t is long. But it does not compile on arm, because int64_t is long long. The type deduction has now two equal choices between int64_t and double to convert my number to, so it declines. With variant<int64_t, string> I wouldn't even have noticed the conversion, because then there is only one available and the compiler would have accepted it.

Similar issue with: `v = 5LL;` Now arm / 32 bit is fine, but x86_64 not anymore.

I get this compiling on both platforms but this is (sometimes) a type conversion with potential side-effects I am not able to foresee: `v = int64_t(5LL);`. Without the LL I wouldn't even be able to express values outside 32bit int.

The INT64_C macro seems to be the most portable and safest way to express this: `v = INT64_C(5);`
But this not nice to read and write anymore.

Is there a similar literal suffix like L/LL for int64_t that is portable?

Comment: A simple solution would be to use a cast instead: `int64_t i = (int64_t)5;`. (And it's fully portable and resolved at compile time.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UL suffix vs uint32\_t cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35483362/ul-suffix-vs-uint32-t-cast)

Comment: Another option could be to define a literal operator on your own: [SO: Fixed-width integer literals in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36406334/7478597) (I could swear that I somewhere read that they might be added to the standard...)

Comment: @scheff: I didn't even expect the c-cast to work, but it seems to work. In the end I prefer not to use c-casts in c++ and would probably write static_cast<int64_t>(...) instead. But then the constructor notation int64_t(...); is nicer to the eyes, at least for me.

The integer literal approach seems to be the best way to go forwards, thanks for the hint.

Comment: I prefer C-casts as I'm too old to get used with the correct C++ casts. In most cases (`dynamic_cast` excluded to which even I got used) it does the intended... ;-)

Comment: @kmdreko: Thanks for the hint, but in the end they just describe my problem in the answers, but not a solution. Or I missed it.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/operator%3D claims that `v = 5L` should always compile, because `double` isn't a candidate for assignment (in the example with `v4`). This seems to be because it is a narrowing conversion so `long&& t = 5l; double x[] = { static_cast<long&&>(t) };` doesn't compile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there are no standard literals for fixed width integer aliases.

One potential workaround would be to use `std::variant<long long, double> v;`. Although `long long` theoretically isn't guaranteed to be exactly 64 bits (it may be wider, but not narrower), it is 64 bits on practically every system that supports `long long` today. The benefit is that `long long` of course has a standard literal. The potential drawback is that the size situation may theoretically change in future.

A more general solution is to give up on using a literal suffix, and instead use a cast: `v = static_cast<int64_t>(5);`.

Another solution is to create a user defined literal as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36406334/2079303) linked in comments:

> ```
> constexpr std::int64_t operator "" _int64(unsigned long long v)
> { return static_cast<std::int64_t>(v); }
> ```

There is a proposal to add literals such as this to the standard library: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1280r2

---

On a related note, there is a proposal to add literals for `std::size_t` and `std::ptrdiff_t`. That proposal suggests core language literals instead of a standard library literals: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0330r3