# UL vs casting to unsigned long

Tags: c, long-integer, unsigned

What's the difference between `160000000UL` and `(unsigned long) 160000000`?

---

**PROBLEM:**

I have a `#define` with the following:

```
#define SYS_CLK (160000000UL / 1000UL)
```

SYS_CLK is different depending on the system clock. I want to know if I can change it to:

```
#define SYS_CLK ((unsigned long)(RCC_MAX_FREQUENCY/*get freq from the system. It returns e.g. 160000000U*/) / 1000UL)
```

And `RCC_MAX_FREQUENCY` is defined as:

```
#define RCC_MAX_FREQUENCY           168000000U
```

Are they the same?

(I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35483362/ul-suffix-vs-uint32-t-cast), but it's not my question.)

Comment: For most practical purposes, there is no difference.  However, your revised `SYS_CLK` macro may not be a compile-time constant — it depends on whether `RCC_MAX_FREQUENCY` is a compile-time constant.'

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `RCC_MAX_FREQUENCY` is also a macro.

Comment: But what sort of macro?  Does it evaluate to an integer constant expression?  It may not matter.  It may be crucial.  It isn't entirely clear to me what you're worried about.  Why are you worried?

Comment: With `#define SYS_CLK (RCC_MAX_FREQUENCY / 1000UL)`, the type of the `SYS_CLK` constant depends on the type of the `RCC_MAX_FREQUENCY` constant. If that used the `ULL` suffix (or is greater than `ULONG_MAX`), then `SYS_CLK` would have type `unsigned long long` (or possibly `long long` if `RCC_MAX_FREQUENCY` has no suffix and is greater than `ULONG_MAX`). The type cast forces it to be `unsigned long`.

Comment: To me this seems as two different questions in one.... please only ask one question at the time

Comment: Mohammad Kholghi, Why do you feel the need for a cast?  `#define SYS_CLK ((RCC_MAX_FREQUENCY) / 1000u)` should be sufficient.  Casting to `long`, etc, is irrelevant in macro processing.

Comment: @IanAbbott I've added more codes. Please check it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  I've added the definition of `RCC_MAX_FREQUENCY` in Q. Please read it.

Comment: @4386427 I didn't get you. Why 2 questions? I've asked a Q, and added more details.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Because The `RCC_MAX_FREQUENCY` is 168000000U, but I need to know if casting, makes it as 168000000UL?

Comment: @MohammadKholghi Depends how `RCC_MAX_FREQUENCY` is eventually used, something not shown in the question.

Comment: @MohammadKholghi Casting with `(unsigned long)` does make `(unsigned long) 160000000` in the C code (not the pre-processing).  But _why_ do you need to know if the constant is  some sort of `long` like `(unsigned long)`?  How is the `long` part important?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I need to make it `long`, so that everybody can use it. It's somehow a library, which is expected to be written in general, so other co-workers/people can just copy and paste to their own projects. (I code for STM32, so `RCC_MAX_FREQUENCY` is a global variable that I'm sure everyone who uses my library, has this variables depending on his device)

Comment: @MohammadKholghi If left as `unsigned`, everybody can still use it. Still unclear why a `long` requirement.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You're right. 32-bits is enough for 160M. I did not think carefully. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica if `UL` means `unsigned long` and it's 64-bits, then how about `ULL`? I think `UL` means 32, then `ULL` is 64. Am I right? I checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4380700/9691976

Comment: Mohammad Kholghi, `ULL` makes the constant some _unsigned_ type and _at least_ as wide as `unsigned long long`.  `UL` makes the constant some _unsigned_ type and _at least_ as wide as `unsigned long`.  `unsigned long` are **at least** 32- bit.  `unsigned long` could be 32-bit, 64-bit or in esoteric implementations 36- bit , etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the difference between `160000000UL` and `(unsigned long) 160000000`?

`160000000UL` is *unsigned* at pre-processing time, `(unsigned long) 160000000` is signed.

When constants are used in a macro at pre-processing time (e.g. `#if math`), the width (`int, long, long long`)  and cast are irrelevant as the width used is `(u)intmax_t`.  The *sign-ness* is relevant.

---

In general, do not force wider constant width with `L` or `LL` unless [needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40637622/2410359).  Do use `U` when sign-ness is needed.

Casting to `(unsigned long)` or using `L` can force the constant to be at least 64-bit, when a value about 160,000,000 only needs 32-bit.  Using an excessive wide type incurs down-convert warnings.  IMO, coders too often ignore/disable such warnings as they are deemed noisy - when in fact they are useful.

Below is OK:

```
#define SYS_CLK ((unsigned long)(RCC_MAX_FREQUENCY) / 1000UL)
```

Yet I would recommend:

```
#define SYS_CLK (RCC_MAX_FREQUENCY / 1000u)
```

Comment: What's the difference between 1000u and 1000U?

Comment: And what if I don't use U? Just `(RCC_MAX_FREQUENCY / 1000)`. `1000` is positive, `1000u` is positive too.

Comment: @MohammadKholghi Differenece between `1000u` and `1000U` is style - same value - same type.  Use what is more clear.

Comment: @MohammadKholghi  "1000 is positive, 1000u" --> Same value different types.  `int` vs. `unsigned`.  A well enabled compiler may complain about about mis-match sign-ness of `RCC_MAX_FREQUENCY / 1000` or `RCC_MAX_FREQUENCY / 1000u`.